# RKObjectPaginator did not send GET request to server

Tags: objective-c, restkit

I have a `RKObjectPaginator` and have set the necessary parameters. But my server did not receive any query.

```
RKURL *patternURL = [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] baseURL] URLByAppendingResourcePath:ResourcePathPattern];

RKObjectPaginator *paginator = [[RKObjectPaginator alloc] initWithPatternURL:patternURL mappingProvider:[self paginationMappingProvider]];
paginator.delegate = self;
[paginator loadPage:0];
```

My log console reads:

```
2012-09-12 20:56:36.975 keytech search ios[1692:c07] Will load page: 0
2012-09-12 20:58:06.613 keytech search ios[1692:c07] D restkit.network:RKRequest.m:436 Sending asynchronous GET request to URL 'http://-MyServerIP-:8080/keytech/GetNextSearchResults?pageSize=25&pageNumber=0.
2012-09-12 20:58:06.613 keytech search ios[1692:c07] T restkit.network:RKRequest.m:402 Prepared GET URLRequest '<NSMutableURLRequest >http://-MyServerIP-:8080/keytech/GetNextSearchResults?pageSize=25&pageNumber=0>'. HTTP Headers: {
    "Content-Length" = 0;
}. HTTP Body: .
```

But no request is send to the server.

Have I done everything right? If I post the URL in my browser, the server responds well. It seems that this query is not send.

I have no clue why this request is not send.

Is there a 'best-practise' example how to use `RKObjectPaginator`?

Answer (score 1):

You might not be able to load page 0.

try [paginator loadPage:1];

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for a sample myself on how to do this. In your case I believe that you are missing the PageCount and ObjectCount properties. It seems to me that you have to set that up manually.

BTW: did you ever resolve it?

Comment: I finally gave up using RKObjectPaginator at this point. This does not mean, that I will try it later again. The answer from Hamish Crittenden looks very promising, starting with page 1.